# Creating test objects for testing purposes without boilerplate code in spring boot

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, integration-testing, spring-test

I am dealing with boilerplate code in my test cases. I use JUnit and Mockito as frameworks for my tests. I am building a rest API and when a create request for example performs from client I get this json deserializes it into a createRequest object, i convert this object into corresponding entity processing it and when the entity is ready and saved in database i convert this entity with the converter to a response object based on role of current user that performs the request ex. UserResponse, AdminResponse, ManagerResponse etc. My problem is that i want the test cases Unit and Integration i want to be isolated from production code and i don't use the converters for test cases. Which is the solution to this problem? How i can avoid the boilerplate code of conversion these objects in order to create the expected response in my test cases?

Currently I manual convert the objects